# How to change text box text by click on button

Tags: c#, .net, button, webforms, textbox

Hello I am beginner in asp.net webforms and i want to copy text of textbox in another textbox when i click in button

my code is :

```csharp
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox15.Text = TextBox6.Text;
}
```

when i fill TextBox6 and click button nothing show in TextBox15

Comment: do you have anything in TestBox6 at the time you clicking the button?
Also put a break point in the statement of assigning the value, and see whether that is hit, when you click the button

Comment: Yes , i write a word like hello, but when i click button nothing show in textbox15

Comment: When you click the button, do you lose the values of both text boxes?

Comment: yes , exactly, thats happend

Comment: Could you provide relevant .aspx code?

Comment: exactly yes i use that

Comment: Can you show us what the `HTML` looks like? At least `TextBox6`, `TextBox15` and `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IsPostBack property in the pade_load event handler to prevent re-validation of the page every time you click the button.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

By the way code of your button click will remain as it is, dont change anything of it, just write the above code on the page load.

I hope it helps

Comment: I think this won't help. `IsPostBack` property does not control if page is posted back (refreshed/reloaded). It only checks if it is posted back. `AutoPostBack` control's property is in charge of that. If `AutoPostBack` is set to `true`, either on frontend, or in code behind, control will postback, otherwise it won't. In this case postback is needed so `AutoPostBack` remains `true`.

Comment: Even if the AutoPostBack of the control is set to True, the value of TextBox6.Text must be populated on TextBox5.Text but after clicking the button twice, or waiting until TextBox16 PostBack when you take the focus out of it and then click the button.

Comment: @MarkoRadivojević I am using visual studio 2013, when you add controls to you page by default the value of AutoPostBack property is set to false, and FYI buttons don't have this property.

Comment: @Hardood My bad, I forgot that button control doesn't have `AutoPostBack` property.

Comment: Yes , I try this and i can solve the problem thank you so much